# Spring 4, JBoss 7, @Configuration Bean equivalent XML - Spring Transactions

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jboss7.x, spring-transactions

It seem like EntityManager is NOT flushing out the changes to the database. What makes this problem harder is that there is no exception thrown. I am using declarative transactions to define my transaction boundaries with the following flow:

SignUpController --> @Transactional: Tx.Start -->  AccountServiceImpl.createAccount --> AccountDAOImpl.createAccount --> Tx.Commit --> SignUpController

From my investigation it seems like:

1.Spring is properly defining the Transaction Boundaries using @Transactional. Hence Transaction are being created

2.Also please Note the I am using the SharedEntityManagerBean, which means I CANNOT explicitly define my transaction boundaries e.g:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(entity);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

The above code results in the following exception: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead

Below is the relevant code and configuration. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

MainConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com",excludeFilters=                {@Filter(Configuration.class)})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MainConfig  {

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
DataSource ds = (DataSource)getFromInitialContext("java:jboss/datasources/PrimaryDB");
return ds;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
 return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource());
}

@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
   EntityManagerFactory emf = (EntityManagerFactory) getFromInitialContext("java:jboss/entityManagerFactory");
return emf;
}

private Object getFromInitialContext(String jndiValue) {
    Context ctx = null;
    Object object = null;
try {
  ctx = new InitialContext();
  object = ctx.lookup(jndiValue);
} catch (NamingException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
return object;
}
}
```

persistance.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="PrimaryDB" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/PrimaryDB</jta-data-source>
    <class>com.domain.entities.Account</class>
    <properties>
        <!-- Bind entity manager factory to JNDI at java:jboss/myEntityManagerFactory -->
        <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name"
            value="java:jboss/entityManagerFactory" />

        <!-- Properties for Hibernate -->
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

AccountServiceImpl:

```
@Service
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {

  @Inject
  AccountDAO accountDAOImpl;

  @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public Account createAccount(SignupForm form, BindingResult formBinding) {
               TransactionDebugUtil.transactionRequired("AccountServiceImpl.createAccount");
   Account account =
        new Account(form.getUsername(), form.getPassword(),form.getFirstName(), form.getLastName());
    try {
      accountDAOImpl.createAccount(account);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      formBinding.rejectValue("username", "user.duplicateUsername",
          "already in use: " + ex.getMessage());
      return null;
    }
    return account;
  }
}
```

AccountDAOImpl.java:

```
@Repository
public class AccountDAOImpl extends GenericJpaDAO<Account> implements    AccountDAO {

  @Override
  @PersistenceContext
  public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
   this.entityManager = entityManager;
   entityManager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);
  }

 @Override
 public void createAccount(Account account) throws     UsernameAlreadyInUseException {
    entityManager.persist(account);
 }
```

Comment: Why do you think information is not getting flushed?

Comment: I cant see the sql being generated in the logs and to confirm I run: select * from account; which returns no result.

Comment: You are using the wrong transaction manager. You are using JPA so you should use the `JpaTransactionManager` and not the `DataSourceTransactionManager`. Also your code is flawed and will break proper td-management, you are catching the exception and setting values, this will make the exception invisible for the tx support and will try to commit instead of rolling back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi the confusion was caused due to using annotations for configuring the transaction manager rather then XML.

Typical XML Configuration for SpringTransaction:

1.

```
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

^It scans all beans in the application context and creates AOP interceptor for those which are annotated.This is done via the SpringTransactionAnnotationParser, which is used by TransactionInterceptor.

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
```

^This is the equivalent configuration bean annotation to allow transactional support

2
. JTA datasource is defined in the persistence.xml. JBoss 7 automatically creates a JTA Transaction Manager and binds it to the following JNDI Location: java:/TransactionManager by default. This Transaction Manager is automatically discovered in spring with the following xml configuration:

```
<tx:jta-transaction-manager />
```

The equivalent annotation configuration for this is:

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
   JtaTransactionManager txManager = new JtaTransactionManager();
   return txManager;
}
```

This resolved my issue. Thanks @geoand for your help.

Answer (score 0):

this kind of behaviour usually happens when we dont have @transactional
on the persistent method.

so add `@Transactional` on top of method like below

```
@Override
@Transactional
 public void createAccount(Account account) throws     UsernameAlreadyInUseException {
    entityManager.persist(account);
 }
```

Comment: Hi thanks for you contribution, but that is incorrect. As long as the  persist method is present within the scope of a transaction, once the transaction commits, the entityManager should automatically flush the changes into the database. It's usually best practice to have your @transactional annotations defined in the service layer.

Answer (score 0):

You are not handling transaction management correctly. Replace your transaction manager bean with:

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
   final JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
   txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
   return txManager;
}
```

Comment: I am using a JTA EntityManager, hence cannot use the JPA TransactionManager you have define above because it gives me the following expection: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: A JTA EntityManager cannot use getTransaction() . However you did guide me in the right direction to resolve my issue.